# Core data migration without reading all of the data into memory?

Tags: ios, objective-c, sqlite, core-data

We have a core data DB (sqlite store) which, for some users, is about 100-150 MB. I wouldn't think that would be too big for a storage system to deal with (even on a mobile device), but we've found that with that size core data DB, ANY lightweight migration takes ~10+ seconds to complete. Even something as simple as adding a completely new independent entity (not related to any other entity). With raw sqlite this would be a create table statement. So, my  question is whether anyone else has seen this and, if so, have they found a workaround to make such simple migrations faster? Specifically, I'm looking for a way to handle adding a new independent entity to an existing core data DB that's ~100-150 MB and have it be quick (i.e., under 5 seconds).

I believe that core data migrations ALWAYS have to read all of the data from the source and write it all to a destination for a migration (which is terrible BTW), but I'm hoping someone can prove me wrong. :) I couldn't find any way to do it with a custom migration either.

I've considered munging the DB with sql directly to basically make the model look like what CoreData would expect (I've done stuff like this to manually "downgrade" a core data DB for debugging purposes), but we really want to avoid doing something like that in production.

**UPDATE:**

For reference, this is the current approach we are taking. This is not a generic solution, but will work for our use case. Unless I get a better answer I'll add this as an answer at some point in the future and accept it.

We're going to deal with this by essentially making the DB smaller. There are 2 out of 15 entities that take up the bulk of the space in the DB (~95%). We're going to create completely separate data models each with one of those entities. This is done without changing the main model at all (hence, no core data migration). We'll then make a task that runs with background priority in GCD that, if any of those entities are found in the main DB, they're moved to the appropriate separate DB and removed from the main DB. This is done in batches with some sleeps between batches so it's less resource intensive and doesn't affect normal app operation. We'll modify the code that accesses those entities to try to get them from the new DB and fall back to the main DB if they're not in there.

In a future update after we find that all, or at least most, of our users have updated their data in the new DBs we'll drop those entities from the main DB.

This leaves us with a small main DB that can have migrations applied quickly and two large DBs that have migrations done more slowly. Those large DBs, in our case, should change less often (maybe never?) and even if they do change there are limited places in the app that require them so we can work around it in the UI (e.g., report some feature as unavailable until we move data).

Comment: SQLite is just very slow. If you use the `com.apple.CoreData.SQLDebug` argument you can see exactly what statements Core Data is issuing; you'll see that when it can do a lightweight migration it is just adding and removing columns and tables.

Comment: Thanks, this is VERY helpful. The slowdown is because of the alphabetical ordering of entities in Z_PRIMARYKEY. The inserted table is before one of the entities that takes a lot of space (there are a LOT of rows for it). Because the Z_ENT id changed for it, core data had to update ALL rows in that table. I might be able to speed it up by just renaming the entity in the model...

Answer (score 2):

A 10-20 second delay for an update to a huge dataset seems perfectly reasonable to me. Just don't do it on the main thread.

This means you'll have to modify the boilerplate Core Data stack setup that you get in the usual Xcode templates. Instead of always setting up the stack on the main thread at launch time, check to see if migration is needed. If so, put up appropriate UI, do the migration in a background thread, and be ready to invoke `beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:` if needed.

Comment: Yeah, I know for a long migration you wouldn't want to run on the main thread else you'll get killed by ios. The question is about avoiding long migrations for simple changes that at least seem like they shouldn't require a data change.

Comment: As I understand it (I don't have a source to cite, sorry), one reason to use Core Data's migration model is its atomicity. A new, valid, intact datastore exists before the old one goes away. That's much safer than your idea of "munging the DB with sql", which could leave your datastore in an incomplete/incoherent state if migration/update is interrupted. 10 seconds to copy 150 MB, once a month (if you modify your datamodel that often), is not a bad tradeoff. Remember that Core Data is not a database, and don't ask it to behave like SQL.

Comment: According to Apples docs (https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/CoreDataVersioning/Articles/vmLightweightMigration.html), lightweight migrations with a SQL store are supposed to be able to be performed in situ which would already invalidate atomicity if SQL statements alone can mess things up (there are ways to protect against this in sqlite anyway). Of course, it also should be fast, but is not. :) I realize that core data isn't SQL, but I'm just finding it's performance sub-par so assume there is something I'm missing.